# How To Clear History & Cache in Google Chrome While Leaving Chrome Extension Local Storage alone?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-cache, local-storage

I have a plugin that I like, and it uses the Local Storage feature. How do I configure my Chrome browser to let me clear everything but leave the  Local Storage feature alone?

This may also be a problem with the new Edge Chromium, too. Evidently, it has a setting that Google Chrome doesn't have -- you can set what gets cleared on closing of the browser.

```
edge://settings/clearBrowsingDataOnClose?search=cache
```

One of those options, either in Google Chrome or Edge Chromium, may be clearing out the Local Storage feature of my favorite plugin when I clear the cache, depending on what item I'm choosing. Unfortunately, Google doesn't tell us what setting affects Local Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Google says that "Clear Site Data" affects Web Storage, which includes Session Storage and Local Storage.

SOURCE: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cdata-that-can-be-deleted

In my test with Edge Chromium and Google Chrome, it clears it with your browser session on websites that may have used it, but leaves your Chrome Extensions and Edge Chromium Extensions alone if they use it.

Comment: This is correct, Clearing storage leaves extensions alone.